# XCODE COMPILE ERROR ON SMS_ADVANCED PLUGIN

Tags: ios, xcode

> Hi all,
>
> Trying compile my app, generates an error in Xcode. My app works fine
> till I add sms_advanced plugin, I use exactly the code given in sample
> example for sending sms via IPHONE (IOS build).
>
> Here are flutter doctor, logs of compile and code used to send an SMS.
>
> Flutter doctor : Flutter doctor log: % flutter doctor Doctor summary
> (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v): [✓] Flutter (Channel
> master, 2.6.0-12.0.pre.837, on macOS 11.6.1 20G224 darwin-arm, locale
> en-FR) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android
> SDK version 31.0.0) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 13.1)
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio (version 2020.3)
> [✓] VS Code (version 1.62.3) [✓] Connected device (2 available)
>
> Compile log:
>
> Running Xcode build... Xcode build done. 11.1s Failed to build iOS app
> Error output from Xcode build: ↳
> ** BUILD FAILED **
>
> Xcode's output: ↳
> /Users/theUser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sms_advanced-1.0.1/ios/Classes/SmsAdvancedPlugin.m:13:4:
> error: unknown receiver 'SwiftSmsAdvancedPlugin'; did you mean
> 'SmsAdvancedPlugin'? [SwiftSmsAdvancedPlugin
> registerWithRegistrar:registrar]; ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> SmsAdvancedPlugin In file included from
> /Users/theUser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sms_advanced-1.0.1/ios/Classes/SmsAdvancedPlugin.m:1:
> /Users/theUser/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/sms_advanced-1.0.1/ios/Classes/SmsAdvancedPlugin.h:3:12:
> note: 'SmsAdvancedPlugin' declared here @interface SmsAdvancedPlugin :
> NSObject ^ 1 error generated. note: Using new build system note:
> Planning note: Build preparation complete note: Building targets in
> parallel
>
> Could not build the precompiled application for the device.
>
> Error launching application on iPhone.

SAMPLE CODE:

```
void main() {
  SmsSender sender = new SmsSender();
  String address = someAddress();
  SmsMessage message = new SmsMessage(address, 'Hello flutter world!');
  message.onStateChanged.listen((state) {
    if (state == SmsMessageState.Sent) {
      print("SMS is sent!");
    } else if (state == SmsMessageState.Delivered) {
      print("SMS is delivered!");
    }
  });
  sender.sendSms(message);
}
```

Can someone help me how to solve this issue please?

Comment: Were you able to identify the fix for this issue?

Comment: Hi, not yet solved